# Changing to static IP android_x86

Tags: android-x86

need some help. I am currently working on a project that needs needs an android operating system. It's running on an Intel Nuc. The device travels around for presentations thus the IP address changes. I am running a local host on the machine. Does anyone know how I can set the IP to be static so I don't need to change the address in my browser? Please note that this is running on a PC and not a traditional mobile device.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am running a local host on the machine"? *localhost* just means *this machine*.

Comment: @DanHulme I am running a local webserver. Every time I change a location the IP changes. So I need to ensure that there is a static ip that I can access via the browser

Comment: Why not just type `http://localhost/` in the browser address bar?

Comment: @DanHulme I did try it but the browser that I am using does not allow me to do this. I am using Kiosk Browser lockdown

Comment: How about `http://127.0.0.1/`?

Comment: Just left the office now sir. Will try that as soon as I am at the office tomorrow. Thanks so much for your help